# final attributes that change

Tags: java, android, arrays, concurrency, scope

We encountered an error that we can't solve so far, without apparent cause or solution.

The error occurs in multiple accesses to an array that contains data loaded from a file.
The ArrayIndexOutOfBounds occurs in various parts of code that works with this array.

The variables seem to randomly change the value. To prevent this we tried to put the modifier "final" in all the class attributes. But they still randomly change the value.

Below, the method "execute ()" and its inner loop "while" it is the application point where the error occurs.

```
public Set<Long> execute(InputStream datIn, int qtd) throws PersistenceException {

        if (this.criterion == null) {
            throw new PersistenceException("Não foi especificado filtro para a busca");
        }

        this.criterion.configure(info);

        try {
            Set<Long> retorno = new HashSet<Long>(qtd);
            byte[] b = new byte[Serializator.BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bl = datIn.read(b, 0, Serializator.BUFFER_SIZE);
            int br = bl, bp = 0, nbp = 0, blockSize, i, p = 0;

            while (p++ < qtd) {
                System.out.println("P = "+p);
                bp = nbp;
                int aux = ByteArrayUtils.toUnsignedShort(b, bp);
                System.out.println("aux = "+aux);
                blockSize = aux + indexBlockSize;
                System.out.println("indexBlockSize = "+indexBlockSize);
                System.out.println("blockSize = "+blockSize);
                if (br < blockSize + 2) {
                    for (i = 0; i < br; i++) {
                        b[i] = b[i + bp];
                    }
                    bl = datIn.read(b, br, Serializator.BUFFER_SIZE - br) + br;
                    bp = 0;
                    br = bl;
                }

                nbp = bp + blockSize;
                br -= blockSize;

                System.out.println("b.length = "+b.length);
                System.out.println("bp = "+bp);
                System.out.println("headerSize = "+headerSize);
                if (this.criterion.doCompare(b, bp, headerSize)) {
                    retorno.add(getSearchedValue(b, bp));
                    if (retorno.size() == this.maxResults) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return retorno;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new PersistenceException(e);
        }
}
```

Below the code of the methods that appear in the "execute ()":

getSearchValue:

```
public long getSearchedValue(byte[] b, int bp) {
    if (this.fieldReturn == -1) {
        return ByteArrayUtils.toLong(b, bp + 2);
    } else {
        if (b[this.bitSetPosition + bp] >= 0) {
            int off = ByteArrayUtils.toShort(b, bp + rIndex) + headerSize + bp;
            return ByteArrayUtils.readOptimizedLong(b, off);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

ByteArraysUtils.toShort():

```
public static short toShort(byte[] byteArray, int off) {
        System.out.println("ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length="+byteArray.length
                +" off = "+off);
        return (short) ((byteArray[off + 1] & 0xFF) | ((byteArray[off] & 0xFF) << 8));
}
```

ByteArraysUtils.toUnsignedShort():

```
public static int toUnsignedShort(byte[] byteArray, int off) {
        System.out.println("ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length="+byteArray.length
                +" off = "+off);
        return ((int) 0) | ((byteArray[off + 1] & 0xFF) | ((byteArray[off] & 0xFF) << 8));
}
```

Criterion.doCompare():

```
public boolean doCompare(byte[] data, int offset, int headerSize) throws PersistenceException {
    System.out.println("doCompare: data.length = "+data.length+" offset = "+offset
            +" this.position = "+this.position);
    if (data[offset + this.position] >= 0) {
        short off = ByteArrayUtils.toShort(data, offset + this.position);
        return this.def.verify(data, off + offset + headerSize);
    } else {
        return this.def.verifyNull();
    }
}
```

Here are some logs of errors generated during execution:

- Error 1:
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  at com.wealthsystems.util.api.array.ByteArrayUtils.toShort(ByteArrayUtils.java:123)
  at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.criterion.Criterion.doCompare(Criterion.java:64)
  at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.DatSearch.execute(DatSearch.java:133)
- Error 2:
  6841 LoginActivity Falha de login java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.criterion.Criterion.doCompare(Criterion.java:61)
- Error 3:
  1002575 LoginActivity Falha de login java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  at com.wealthsystems.util.api.array.ByteArrayUtils.toUnsignedShort(ByteArrayUtils.java:129)

As we can see, the error happens in many different locations, but the value of the variable is always the same, ie, the error seems to be random. This was verified with the print of the variables (as when we turn on debug the error does not happen), and through the prints we see a curious change of variables. Below are some examples of print that were generated:

Print 1:

```
P = 746
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 22400
aux = 100
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 158
b.length = 32767
bp = 22400
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 22400 this.position = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 22410
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 22465

P = 747
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 22558
aux = 99
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 157
b.length = 32767
bp = 22558
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 22558 this.position = 10
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.criterion.Criterion.doCompare(Criterion.java:62)
     at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.DatSearch.execute(DatSearch.java:121)
     at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.retrieve.DatRetrieve.search(DatRetrieve.java:62)
```

Note that in "doCompare ()" will be accessed the index "[offset + this.position]," but the error is accused in index access 22568. The index is smaller than the size of the vector ("data.length").

Print 2:

```
P = 578
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 28651
aux = 114
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 172
b.length = 32767
bp = 28651
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 28651 this.position = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 28661
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 28716

P = 579
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 28823
aux = 114
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 22618
b.length = 32767
bp = 0
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 0 this.position = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 65

P = 580
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 22618
aux = 65280
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 87784
b.length = 32767
bp = 0
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 0 this.position = 10
P = 581
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 87784
28493 LoginActivity Falha de login java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.wealthsystems.util.api.array.ByteArrayUtils.toUnsignedShort(ByteArrayUtils.java:131)
at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.DatSearch.execute(DatSearch.java:98)
at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.retrieve.DatRetrieve.search(DatRetrieve.java:62)
```

Note the execution p = 579.
The aux value is 114. The value of indexBlockSize is 58. The blockSize value should be 172. But it appears a value of blockSize = 22618.

Print 3:

```
P = 1
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 0
aux = 144
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 202
b.length = 32767
bp = 0
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 0 this.position = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 65

P = 2
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 202
aux = 96
indexBlockSize = 58
blockSize = 154
b.length = 32767
bp = 202
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 202 this.position = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 212
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 267

P = 3
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 356
aux = 115
indexBlockSize = -7696
blockSize = -7581
b.length = 32767
bp = 356
headerSize = 65
doCompare: data.length = 32767 offset = 356 this.position = 10
ByteArrayUtils: toShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 366
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = 421

P = 4
ByteArrayUtils: toUnsignedShort: byteArray.length=32767 off = -7225 61680
LoginActivity Falha de login java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.wealthsystems.util.api.array.ByteArrayUtils.toUnsignedShort(ByteArrayUtils.java:131)
at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.search.DatSearch.execute(DatSearch.java:98)
at com.wealthsystems.persistence.impl.retrieve.DatRetrieve.search(DatRetrieve.java:62)
```

This is the most critical error, because the variable "indexBlockSize" is private and initialized in the constructor and is no longer modified, but in the middle of running it changes the value for indexBlockSize = -7696 (execution P = 3).

**Devices in which the error occurs:**
 - iBAK-775 (Firmware: 2.1-update1-1.0.0) (Kernel: 2.6.25) (frequency: error very common);
 - LG Optimus One P500 (Android version: 2.2.2) (kernel: 2.6.32.9) (frequency: error uncommon);
 - Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 (Android: 2.2) (frequency: common error);
 - Samsung I5800 Galaxy 3 (Android 2.2) (frequency: common error).

**Devices in which the error never happened:**
 - All the devices above, when run in debug mode in Eclipse;
 - Emulator on any version of Android;
 - Motorola Spice XT300 (firmware: 2.1-update1) (kernel: 2.6.29);
 - Samsung Galaxy 5 (GT-I5500B) (firmware: 2.1-update1) (kernel: 2.6.29);
 - Motorola Xoom (Android 3.0);
 - Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 (Android 3.0).

Unfortunately we could not isolate the error in an external code to our application, that you were able to reproduce the error. All attempts to isolate the code out of our application did not generate the error. But hope you can give us some information about what is happening to us!

Our research on the internet about this error showed only this page: http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/96129.html. Looks like someone went through similar problems to ours, but there is no solution in the discussion.

---

The declarations of attributes and the class constructor:

```
private byte fieldReturn;
private EntityInfo info;
private final short rIndex, indexBlockSize;
private ICriterion criterion = null;
private int headerSize;
private int maxResults;
private int bitSetPosition;

public DatSearch(byte fieldReturn, EntityInfo info) {
    this.fieldReturn = fieldReturn;
    this.bitSetPosition = (this.fieldReturn == -1) ? -1 : 10 + (fieldReturn * 2);
    this.info = info;
    this.rIndex = (fieldReturn >= 0) ? (short) (10 + (fieldReturn << 1)) : 0;
    short qtdIndices = (short) info.getMapper().getIndexes().length;
    this.indexBlockSize = (short) (10 + (qtdIndices << 1));
    this.headerSize = indexBlockSize + info.getBitSetLength();
}
```

I tried putting all the variables of this class in another class outside and read it with gets and sets, but this workaround did not work.

Comment: 1. how many threads are doing this? 2. how exactly have you defined the indexBlockSize variable? and the final keyword only means that you can't change the value of the variable within its scope and the variable goes out of scope and is modifiable. I have one more thought please show all the usages of your indexBlockSize variable and how it's defined. thank you.

Comment: you can also read about mutable and immutable objects/types in java and garbage collection too

Comment: 1. Only one thread.
2. I added declarations of attributes and the class constructor.

The indexBlockSize variable is used only in this method and never written.

Comment: are you sure that DatSearch is being called only once ? make your variable as `private static final short indexBlockSize;`

Comment: It is called many times, but always by the same thread, we confirmed this through debugging and printing the current thread name. Also, it is always created a new instance of DatSearch and the method is called only once on this instance, what should prevent threading issues.

Comment: well if I'm getting it right you call the constructor of the class everytime and set this final value each time. right? try to use a singleton for this class preventing it from being created many times. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem only occurred in old devices and old Android versions. Above 2.3 version it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling your execute code multiple times. In that case, different threads might be accessing your arrays. While one is changing the values, the other thread might be reading them...

Take a look at the java synchronized keyword. This keyword is used to prevent different threads from accessing the same values. [more about synchronization](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2002/jw-0607-java101.html)

so, when reading/writing to and from your array, surround those calls with synchronized e.g.:

```
byte[] b;
synchronized(b)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[Serializator.BUFFER_SIZE];
}

synchronized(b)
{
    b[i] = b[i + bp];
}
```

you can do this for complete functions as well:

```
public synchronized long getSearchedValue(byte[] b, int bp) {
    ... your code
}
```

Be sure to do that, everywhere you change the arrays that are crashing.

Comment: It is always the same thread that calls the method. 
We synchronized all access to b and the execute() method. But it did not work.

Comment: In that case, i don't have a clue. Sorry!